# returning a 'pointer' which is required to be held by a smart pointer

Tags: c++, boost, tr1

I have a project which I would like to make more use of smart pointers. Overall, I have been successful in this goal. However, I've come across one things which I'm not sure what the "best practice" is.

Basically I would like to return a "pointer" from a function, but **require** that the user hold it in a smart pointer. Not only that, I don't want to mandate a particular smart pointer (shared vs. scoped).

The problem is mostly that there doesn't seem be to a proper way to upgrade a `scoped_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` (that would be the ideal solution i think). I understand why they didn't do this, as it would allow transferring of ownership which can lead to some issues like those `std::auto_ptr` has.

However, transferring of ownership seems like a good idea for *this* case. So my idea is like this:

```
// contrived example of factory pattern
std::auto_ptr<A> func() { return std::auto_ptr<A>(new A); }
```

This works "ok" since both `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr` have constructors which take ownership from a `std::auto_ptr`.

So my question is, is this good practice? Is there a better solution? The only real alternative I've been able to come up with is using a template template as the return value like this:

```
// similar to above example
template <template <typename> class P>
P<A> func() { return P<A>(new A); }
```

which actually could work well except that I think it would need some work to get it to work with a `scoped_ptr` too.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `std::auto_ptr` is **the** good practice, in fact [such example](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#memory-leaks) was suggested
by Bjarne Stroustrup.

The move semantics of `auto_ptr` gives you right tools to deal with it.

For example:

```
auto_ptr<Foo> make_foo()
{
    return auto_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
}

Foo *raw_pointer=make_foo().release();
shared_ptr<Foo> shared_pointer=make_foo();
auto_ptr<Foo> auto_pointer=make_foo();
```

If you return `shared_ptr` you can't fallback to normal pointer, with `auto_ptr` you can. You can allways upgrade `auto_ptr` to shared but not other direction.

Another important point, `shared_ptr` uses atomic reference-counting, that is much slower
that simple and yet fully efficient job that `auto_ptr` does.

P.S.: `scoped_ptr` is just version of `auto_ptr` for poors --- it is non-copyable and does
not have default constuctor. It is more like "less confusing" version of `auto_ptr`, in comparison to `shared_ptr` it is not in tr1. Generally there no much advantages of using
`scoped_ptr` over `auto_ptr`

Comment: shared_ptr in the single thread build doesn't use atomic reference-counting.

Comment: You right, but by default boost is build in multi-threaded version.

Comment: The advantage of using scoped_ptr over auto_ptr is when you want to make it clear you aren't supposed to copy the pointer. You simply can't with scoped_ptr. It's about conveying your intentions, just like your example does with auto_ptr and transfer of ownership.

Comment: Scott Meyers also has a pretty thorough article on this at http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/resourceReturnProblem.txt.

Answer (score 3):

If you build a factory that's ok that you simply return a pointer. And the user of your factory can make his own decision how to and where to put this pointer.

If you need to enforce to use smart pointer you have to restrict choice as you don't want them to use "wrong" ones.

So boost::shared_ptr. But better to typedef it then to MyClassPtr or MyClass::ptr.

Still, factories they are like "new". When I want I put result of new inside of std::auto_ptr. But I don't want to be forced to call "release" all the times when I don't want smart pointer.

Comment: true, but I'd like to enforce the use of a smart pointer if possible.

Comment: I agree, we are all adults here. Return a naked pointer and let the user of the code decide how to best catch the return value. I believe that shared_ptr's constructor from an auto_ptr is going away (auto_ptr is going to be deprecated).

Comment: when auto_ptr is depricated in C++0x, unique_ptr will be replacing it.  I'd switch to returning unique_ptr then.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 you should be able to use `std::unique_ptr` as the other smart pointer types have constructors that take a `std::unique_ptr`.  If you maintain an internal list of such resources then you'd probably want to use `std::shared_ptr`.