# Does dereferencing an rvalue pointer produce a lvalue?

Tags: c++, memory

I have the simple code:

```
int & i = *(new int(100));
```

As far as I know, the RHS of the equation is a rvalue.. How can an rvalue bound to a lvalue reference?

Also if this is legal, does it produce the desired result always, or it is an undefined behavior? And if I do `delete &i`, will it be an undefined behavior too?

Comment: Asked yesterday... ^^

Comment: @H2CO3 I saw that question and left a comment of this question but no one answered so I created my own question. I am asking more fundamentals in terms of value types, which were not discussed in the answers in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side of the assignment is a dereferenced pointer, and this is an lvalue, so  there no problem binding an lvalue reference to it. The standard specifically gives the example of a dereferenced pointer in its definition of an lvalue (3.10/1):

> An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object. [ Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then *E is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E points. As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. — end example ]

There is no undefined behavior because `i` refers to a valid object.

Your question about `delete` is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233987/deleting-a-reference).